# How to get value of hidden field in jquery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am iterating loop over Div and in that div assigning encoded array as value to hidden field and want to get value of that hidden field in  each loop but getting undefiened

```js
var port_ofAir = null; $(".sublocation_div").find('.sublocation').each(function(index,value1){
    port_ofAir = $(this).find(".port_arr").value;

  });
  console.log(port_ofAir)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="arr_port" class="port_arr" id="arr-port" value="[{"id":34,"client_id":"2"}]">
```

I want to get that array in jquery function

please any suggestion

Comment: try `.val()'. not sure but try it

Comment: You would use `.val()` in jQuery to get the value of a form element.  Though that particular form element looks like broken HTML syntax.  The `value` there is just `"[{"`, everything else is outside of the `value` attribute.

Comment: can you show us the `div` element that has class of `sublocation_div` ?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you need to use `.val()` instead of `.value`:

```
port_ofAir = $(this).find(".port_arr").val();
```

Comment: Still getting Undefiened

Comment: Are you sure it's a descendant of the `.sublocation` element you're looping over?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you need to use `.val()`, and not `value`. Also, you can put a specific jQuery selector for hidden fields using `input[type=hidden]`

```
$(".sublocation_div").find('.sublocation').each(function(index,value1){
    var port_ofAir = $(this).find("input[type=hidden].port_arr").val();
 }
```